# PIC interrupt based soft UART timing trouble

Tags: assembly, timer, interrupt, pic, uart

I've tried to implement a software **UART** on a pic 18F452 using timer interrupts - although I'm a begginer with microcontrollers - and I can't get the timing working. I'm using MPLAB asm for compilation and the PICkit 2 for programming.

```
LIST P=18F452
include <P18F452.inc>
CONFIG WDT=OFF, LVP=OFF, OSC=HS, CP0=OFF

variable cyclesPerBaud=1            ; 1 cycle(s) per baud
variable cyclesInt=0xFFFF           ; counter in 16 bit timer
variable freq = 20000000            ; clock frequency 20Mhz
variable baud = 9600                    ; baud rate
variable cyclesMain=33              ; cycles in Main program branch (intr->checkBitCounter->startStopBit->transfer)
variable cyclesIdle=16              ; cycles in Idle branch (intr->Idle)
variable offset = (freq/(4*baud))/(cyclesPerBaud)
variable initOffset = cyclesInt - offset
variable durrOffset = cyclesInt - offset + cyclesMain
variable hurrOffset = cyclesInt - offset + cyclesIdle

cblock 0x20
    char                    ; character to send
    bitCounter      ; bits left to send
    startStopBit    ; checks to send start of stop bit
    buffer              ; buffer where char is rotated
    cycle                   ; the current cycle in cyclesPerBaud starting high
endc

org 0000h
    goto main
org 0008h
    goto intr

main
bcf OSCCON, SCS     ; use primary clock
bsf RCON, IPEN      ; enable priority levels

; interrupt config:
bsf INTCON, GIEH    ; enable high priority interrupts
bcf INTCON, GIEL    ;   disable low priority interrupts
bsf INTCON, TMR0IE; enable TMR0 interrupts
bcf INTCON, INT0IE; dis. ext. interrupts
bcf INTCON, RBIE    ; dis. rb port change int.
bcf INTCON, TMR0IF; clear the TMR0 intr. flag bit
bcf INTCON, INT0IF; 
bcf INTCON, RBIF    ;

bsf INTCON2, TMR0IP; set TMR0 high priority

; timer 0 config:   
bcf T0CON, TMR0ON   ; temp. disable timer
bcf T0CON, T08BIT   ; 16 bit counter
bcf T0CON, T0CS     ; T0CKI pin input as source
bcf T0CON, T0SE     ; switch on falling edge
bsf T0CON, PSA      ; disable prescaler
bcf T0CON, T0PS2    ; doesn't really matter
bcf T0CON, T0PS1    ; -||-
bcf T0CON, T0PS0    ; -||-

; init output registers and variables
clrf TRISD
clrf LATD
movlw 0xFF
movwf PORTD             ; our output port set to high (serial 0 - but not sure about that)
movlw b'01111111' ; symbol to send
movwf char
movlw cyclesPerBaud
movwf cycle             ; unused
clrf bitCounter     ; zeros
clrf startStopBit   ; zeros
clrf buffer             ; zeros
; eof init 
movlw LOW initOffset    ; dunno why but HIGH has to be reversed with LOW
movwf TMR0H             
movlw HIGH initOffset   
movwf TMR0L             
bsf T0CON, TMR0ON   ; turn on timer

loop 
goto loop                   ; waiting for the     interrupt

intr                ; main branch: 8 cycles
btfss INTCON, TMR0IF
    retfie
bcf T0CON, TMR0ON

; had to comment this section out - didn't want to work with it - dunno why
;   decf cycle, F
;   btfss STATUS, Z
;       goto idle
;   movlw cyclesPerBaud
;   movwf cycle

checkBitCounter             ; all branches until 'tmr_ret': 16 cycles
movf bitCounter, F
btfss STATUS, Z
    goto rotateBuffer

;startStopBit

movf startStopBit, F
btfss STATUS, Z
    goto stopCopy
movlw 0x8
movwf bitCounter
movf char, W
movwf buffer
rlncf buffer, F
movlw 0x00

transfer
movwf PORTD
decf bitCounter, F
btfsc STATUS, Z
    incf startStopBit, F

tmr_ret         ; 5 cycles (+8 from intr = 13 cycles)
movlw LOW durrOffset    ; dunno why but HIGH has to be reversed with LOW
movwf TMR0H             
movlw HIGH durrOffset   
movwf TMR0L 

bsf T0CON, TMR0ON
retfie

stopCopy
clrf startStopBit
movlw 0xFF
nop
goto transfer

rotateBuffer
rrncf buffer, F
movf buffer, W
nop
nop
nop
nop
goto transfer   

idle        ; 5 cycles (+7 from intr = 12 cycles)
movlw LOW hurrOffset    ; dunno why but HIGH has to be reversed with LOW
movwf TMR0H             
movlw HIGH hurrOffset   
movwf TMR0L 

bsf T0CON, TMR0ON
retfie

end
```

So I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? I mean the pic is sending stuff on `PORTD`, `0` as it's supposed to but it's not the data it's supposed to be sending. When I peak what is transmitted (with `Realterm`), the byte being sent is `11011111` or `10111111` and sometimes `11111111` instead of `01111111`.

I'm guessing I'm missing something about the timings but not sure what?

Also since I started using 'variables' in the code I noticed that I had to copy the lower part off timing offsets with HIGH and high bytes with LOW into the TMR0H:L registers - anybody knows why it works that way? Maybe I'm confusing the significance of these registers: I used them before as if the TMR0H register would hold the more significant 8 bits of the 2 byte counter - is that correct?

Anyway, I'd appreciate any help. 
Thanks,
Drinker

Comment: You need to measure the output using an oscilloscope, which will reveal any timing issues.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought either so as I did just that I was quite surprised. I tried to send the byte 01010101 to get and easy recognizable pattern and it turned out that the bit switch duration is about 6,2us which gives a baud rate of 161290,32. Well off from the expected value of 9600 :/. Well, trying to fix that I noticed that it didn't matter what offset I put into the TMR0H and TMR0L registers. The baud rate was always the same which makes me pretty certain that the error lies with my TMR0 config. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Still working this issue?

Comment: Yes, although I am way past the stage of making the basic stuff work. Sending any arbitrary message via bit banging works fine but I still have trouble receiving a message. I need to work on my timing I think. And you can imagine that the source code has changed significantly.

Comment: Still working this issue?.  You need to add @chux to your reply, then SO will send a message to me.  I did not come across your post again till today.  BTW on receiving, be sure to quick detect the leading edge, (interrupt / polling), move _half_ bit for next sample and then _one_ bit for subsequent samples.  Should your sample at the first half bit indicate the start bit is gone, ignore and ready yourself for a new transmission.